# submit_tag is not working with correct css in rails4 view

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, view

Hi I have to give following view in my rails code

```
<div class="col s12 m2"> 
   <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-medium custom_btn_gray right margin_T20" type="submit" name="action">Search  
  </button>
</div>
```

So for this I had included following rails view code :

```
<div class='col s12 m2'>
   <%= submit_tag('search', class: 'btn waves-effect waves-light btn-medium custom_btn_gray right margin_T20')%>
</div>
```

which further gives this type of html:

```
<div class="col s12 m2">
            <i class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-medium custom_btn_gray right margin_T20 waves-input-wrapper" style=""><input type="submit" class="waves-button-input" value="search" name="commit"></i>
  </div>
```

But I dont want this I want like the above html . Please guide me where am going wrong . Thanks in advance.

Comment: this shouldn't happened maybe you have overridden submit_tag please check your helpers.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `button_tag`:

```
<%= button_tag('search', class: 'btn waves-effect waves-light btn-medium custom_btn_gray right margin_T20')%>
```

Here is the [doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-button_tag)

Comment: sorry i can use button_tag.because i use form tag first to implement form so to submit this form . i have to use submit_tag.

_

Comment: I am pretty sure that if you do something like this `<%= form_tag('/posts') do -%>
  <div><%= button_tag 'search' %></div>
<% end -%>` it will work

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<div class='col s12 m2'>
 <%= submit_tag "Search", :class => "btn waves-effect waves-light btn-medium custom_btn_gray right margin_T20" %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Then try this using button_tag

```
<%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn waves-effect waves-light btn-medium custom_btn_gray right margin_T20") do %> Search
<% end %>
```